# Can't send mail from localhost/xampp

Tags: php, gmail, xampp

Failed to connect to mailserver at "mail.google.com" port 587, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in **php.ini** or use `ini_set()`

I configured my xampp php.ini and sendmail.ini file to use my Gmail account for sending email from my PHP script. i am using xampp. after changing the [mail function] part of my php.ini looks like this (i have deleted commented outlines for simplicity)

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mail.google.com
smtp_port = 587
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

and my sendmail.ini file looks like this

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=mail.google.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=babar+gmail.com
auth_password=**********
```

So what have I missed? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Sounds like a network connectivity issue. Perhaps your Internet provider isn't allowing outgoing connections on that port?

Comment: please tell something more. how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong SMTP settings for gmail. The correct ones are:

In php.ini

```
[mail function]
;SMTP = localhost
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_path = "c:\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

In sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
auth_username=me@example.com
auth_password=**********
```

Remeber: If you have enabled [2 step authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en), you have to create an application specific password.

Comment: the problem still exists. will u please paste the content of the sendmail.ini file. i m stuck with it.

Comment: @buet_baba Oops! I given you wrong answer earlier. Now try this. It is tested and working in my PC.

Comment: no, it's not working. can you please send me your php.ini file file and sendmail folder please. i can't get it done. one more thing, which version of xampp do you use?

Comment: It is working here. May be some other problem your side. Maybe firewall

Comment: do you have any idea how firewall can stop my application from processing?

Comment: Firewall can prevent outgoing connections to google smtp server

Comment: in that case i have disabled firewall and tried. but no result. :(

Comment: Don't have any idea! sorry.

Comment: @VarunAgw you are missed semicolon at last of the lines in sendmail.ini, Is it ok??

Comment: @151291 Semicolon are used for commenting purpose. Anything that follows semicolon is ignored by the parser

Comment: @VarunAgw but we can use at the end of statement right? else how it will be separated from one to another statement? it seems same and single line... that's why asked you. who is reading line by line? how it is differs variable and value?

Comment: @151291 I don't exactly understand what you mean. Each statement are in new line so that seperates them. `smtp_ssl=tls` Characters before `=` sign are considered variable and characters after `= ` signs are considered their value

Answer (score 0):

set the smtp_ssl=auto as smtp_ssl=true

because google's smtp server needs ssl

Comment: i have tried this but hasn't worked. the problem is still there.