# How do you use PHP to send form data as a message?

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I need to have the visitor of my website send form data (such as a contact form to my email via PHP. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GET/POST query and using tag 
[html forms / w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
for example

```
.html page: 
<form method="GET" action="send.php">
<input name="fieldname" type="text" placeholder="You text here...">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

send.php
<?php

if (isset($_GET['fieldname']) {
   // you code here..
}
```

example send email by function mail()
[about mail() function on php.net](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php)

```
$from = 'fromemailsend@mail';
$to = 'emailtosend@mail';
$subject = 'your subject';
$message = 'your<br>message<br>in html code';
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Author <' .$to . ' >' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$author.' <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```