# PHP Email Form Code Not Emailing

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm not sure why this doesn't go anywhere. I set it up exactly like the code from this thread: [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)

I changed the email address and it still never sends it to me. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Please help!

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "email@example.com"; // this is your Email address
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$subject = "Form submission";
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
$message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
$message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is executed in a local server ?

Comment: it is not in a local server. I thought it was as easy as adding this code, but it sounds like there are steps to take to make it work on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to setup your mail server:

Are you getting this?

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini

It is easier to use a project instead like PHPmailer.

Comment: I am getting no error at all, I will check out PHPmailer. Thanks!