# How to send an email from PHP and make the form fields responsive

Tags: php, html, forms, contact-form

This is my code were to I insert `send.php`

The code is form a theme and they forgot to include a send.php or contact.php.

So I need to know were to insert something like this "sendcontact.php" in the existing code listed below.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-8 animated fadeInLeft">
           <h3 class="subTitle-contact">GET <span>IN TOUCH</span></h3>
           <p>veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni.</p>
           <div class="contact-form">
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Your Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Phone No:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">E-Mail Address:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Company:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputName">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
           <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputMessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="inputMEssage"></textarea>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="submit-button">
                  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              </form>  
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)