# Error in sending email from php Code

Tags: php, email

[image]

The above error is occurring while we sent email from php code my code is

```
<?php 
//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "abc@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
   // $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    //$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    // You cannot use header and echo together. It's one or the other.
    //}
?>
```

it is refered from [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)

the error is as Follows:

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550  No such
>   user here in D:\InetPub\vhosts\aaa.com\httpdocs\sendform.php on line
>   15
>
> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550  No such
>   user here in D:\InetPub\vhosts\aaa.com\httpdocs\sendform.php on line
>   16

Comment: Add your error as text and remove commented code from sample

Comment: i had put it as image .

Comment: i wrote the error as text in the above question

Answer (score 0):

The error is returned by Gmail SMTP server and tells you that the e-mail address your script sends mail to doesn't exist on Gmail servers.

It's not a PHP error.

Comment: so i ned to put via smtp only