# How to fix HTML with drop down values and email send bottom

Tags: html

I am setting up my menu and want to use drop down options for customers to select items and place email orders.

The following is what I have done so far but when I send the email it goes no where. Just want you to know I have no clue about html coding, I am learning because I would like to use this on my website.

```html
<form>

  <form method="post" action="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">

    Name:<br>

    <input type="text" name="name"><br> E-mail:

    <br>

    <input type="text" name="email"><br>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Fries">Fries</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="os0">
            <option value=>Small

              <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Flavors">Flavors</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <select name="os0">
                    <option value=>Garlic Parmesan

                      <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />

                      <input type="reset" value="Reset">

  </form>
```

I would like to receive via email orders from customers that reflect the options above. This is just one item but if I can get it to work I will applied the html code to all the items on my menu.

Comment: You need to implement some backend processing to handle the POSTed form. This can be done with NodeJs, Python, Php, .Net to name a few. Or you cold use a service like campaign monitor or Mailchimp to handle the backend for you

Comment: Please follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382062/1193179

Comment: In the provided code there is a form nested in another form, a lack of `<label> tags`, unclosed `<td>` elements. Correcting these items before trying to add backend communications would be wise.

Comment: The POSTED form (or email test) includes signs such as = + & "on0" "os0", and others similar sings in between items. For example the Name and the Phone Number an = and & appeared in between them. I just need to figure out how to   tell HTML to ignore these signs and to separate by paragraphs.