# Unable to send PHP form

Tags: php, html

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script), I have created a form for my [landing page](https://liderplay.es), and I expected it to work, but I don't see where it is failing, as nothing happens (no mail sent and no echo message) when you click on the button.

PHP (form.php):

```
   <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to         = "my@email.com"; 
    $from       = $email; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $subject    = "Nuevo lead";
    $message    = $first_name . " " . $phone . " " . $email . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n";
    $headers    = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" 
      name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate">

    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <div class="flex-md-wrap">
            <div class="mc-field-group flex-md-1">
                <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="Nombre" autocomplete='given-name'>
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group flex-md-1">
                <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email" autocomplete='email'>
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group flex-md-1">
                <input type="number" value="" name="phone" id="mce-PHONE" placeholder="Teléfono" autocomplete='tel'>
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn--secondary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone have a clue on what is going on?

Comment: Define "nothing happens"? Does the page reload but no email is sent? Or does literally nothing happen?

Comment: Corrected in the post. Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you see in dev tools / console if POST is actually being sent, and what the value is?

Comment: Try var_dump( your mail function signature), and see what it's printed

Comment: No POST is actually being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form submit seems OK but as you've not enabled error reporting that's why **undefined variable issue of** `$email` variable is not visible to you and I assume this is causing you the problem.

To enable error reporting, add this line at the top your form.php file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also move this line `$from = $email;` after `$email = $_POST['email'];`

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$from  = $email;
```

Comment: Good catch. Trying to bug hunt without error reporting is a quick path toward grey hair!

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and the results. It remains the same. I don't see any error messages. Many thanks.

Comment: then `var_dump($_POST);`  and also check the `mail()` function response. It may also cause the issue that's why last line of echo not showing

Comment: I tried but it does nothing. I'm stuck.

Comment: It is doing something according to console.  But its getting 404

Comment: Got "Mail Sent. Thank you test, we will contact you shortly."  after clicking on the button so....

Comment: Yes, he's fixed the 404 now

Answer (score 0):

I went to your site.  Clicking the link sends back a 404 error with this message through dev tools:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL
>   /form.php&c=jQuery19008959887418623141_1563041041943&first_name=Geoger+&email=bill@bigboy.com&phone=3&submit=ENVIAR
>   was not found on this server.

Error is pretty self-explanatory - either you don't have the file created, its named wrong, its in the wrong folder for the server to find, your routing isn't pointing to the right file / path, etc.  Your form on that page is working, the button is working.

While your code may be correct, and you may have followed the solution perfectly, you need more than just the code - you need the infrastructure behind it for the back-end PHP, and to have it all wired up correctly.  Even if the code is perfect, if the server can't find the file, it will always 'do nothing'.

Your site looks fantastic, by the way, just need to do some research on those infrastructure points I think.