# I have a HTML form that uses a POST request and PHP file to send me an email automatically, but it isn't working...any advice?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have a form that uses an HTML form, http post request, and PHP backend to automatically send me the data that a user inputs into the form. The submission works as expected, but I am not getting an email. My email is also run by outlook. Not sure if it's an encryption thing.

HTML Code

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="email-box">
        <input class="tbox" id="email_box" name="email" type="email" style="cursor: pointer;" placeholder="Enter your email">
        <button class="btn" id="email_btn" type="submit" name="button">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
</form>
<!-- Snipped JavaScript validation -->
```

PHP

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'me@website.com';
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
if (!preg_match(
    "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
    $email_address)) {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "New Vrify subscription: $email_address";
    $email_body = "You have a new subscriber. " .
        "Here are the details:\n Email: $email_address \n " .
        $headers = "From: subscriber@website.com";
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this post similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script?rq=1

Comment: For mailing I often use [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/), or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that has more features than the `mail()` function. It also allows easier access to SMTP servers that can send on your behalf as well.

Comment: where are you hosting your web site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: No that post doesn't work. @hppycoder

Comment: @DCR I am on bluehost

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular no it does not

Comment: @Tom That's great then please put the output from Tangentially's post "Make sure error reporting is enabled and set to report all errors" section. We can then see why your server isn't sending the e-mail. The PHP function may be successful but the server might not be configured to send email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the full solution, but as far as I'm aware
`"New Vrify subscription: $email_address"`
is not valid. Instead, concatenate them using the `.` operator
`"New Vrify subscription:".$email_address`

Do the same to the other variables you have, I had the same issue when working on the following php:

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] ?? 'GET') == "POST") {

    $msg ="New message from mysite!\n".$_POST["message"]."\nReply Email:".$_POST["email"];

    mail("me@gmail.com", time(), $msg,"From: contact@mysite");
}
```

Comment: fyi `"New Vrify subscription: $email_address"` is valid, it uses double quotes. Single quotes wouldn't work

Comment: What does your comment do that's different from what the OP has already tried?

Comment: @brombeer I was unaware that double quotes allowed this, I had issues with placing variables inside strings so I opted for concatenation.

Comment: @hppycoder aside from providing (albeit an extremely basic) valid solution it doesnt do much I suppose