# How to execute the php script for this?

Tags: php

I have an HTML form which I will tailor later as a personal feedback form, if someone submits the form, I want the responses to be sent to my email id. I googled about it and apparently, it can be done with PHP but I'm not familiar with the PHP script, can someone give me a headstart using the first few labels, I will try to write the rest on my own, this is the code

```
<form id="survey-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        id="name"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        id="email"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter your Email"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label id="number-label" for="number"
        >Age<span class="clue">(optional)</span></label
      >
      <input
        type="number"
        name="age"
        id="number"
        min="10"
        max="99"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Age"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Which option best describes your current role?</p>
      <select id="dropdown" name="role" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select current role</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="job">Full Time Job</option>
        <option value="learner">Full Time Learner</option>
        <option value="preferNo">Prefer not to say</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
      <label>
        <input
          name="user-recommend"
          value="definitely"
          type="radio"
          class="input-radio"
          checked
        />Definitely</label
      >
      <label>
        <input
          name="user-recommend"
          value="maybe"
          type="radio"
          class="input-radio"
        />Maybe</label
      >

      <label
        ><input
          name="user-recommend"
          value="not-sure"
          type="radio"
          class="input-radio"
        />Not sure</label
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p>
        What is your favorite feature of freeCodeCamp?
      </p>
      <select id="most-like" name="mostLike" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled selected value>Select an option</option>
        <option value="challenges">Challenges</option>
        <option value="projects">Projects</option>
        <option value="community">Community</option>
        <option value="openSource">Open Source</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p>
        What would you like to see improved?
        <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span>
      </p>

      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="front-end-projects"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Front-end Projects</label
      >
      <label>
        <input
          name="prefer"
          value="back-end-projects"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Back-end Projects</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="data-visualization"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Data Visualization</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="challenges"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Challenges</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="open-source-community"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Open Source Community</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="gitter-help-rooms"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Gitter help rooms</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="videos"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Videos</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="city-meetups"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />City Meetups</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="wiki"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Wiki</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="forum"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Forum</label
      >
      <label
        ><input
          name="prefer"
          value="additional-courses"
          type="checkbox"
          class="input-checkbox"
        />Additional Courses</label
      >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Any comments or suggestions?</p>
      <textarea
        id="comments"
        class="input-textarea"
        name="comment"
        placeholder="Enter your comment here..."
      ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: See how to retrieve form data : https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php
After that you can use php function mail https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail

Comment: Thanks Gildas! This definitely gave me more confidence, I feel like I can understand this and do it!

Comment: I would strongly recommend using some mail library (like PHPMailer or similar) over using the low level `mail()`-function. Using a library also allows you to connect directly to a SMTP server and won't require you to install/set up anything on the server. Using `mail()`, you need to configure and set up something like Sendmail or similar on the server.

Comment: "*can someone give me a headstart*" - if you search for "*php form send email*" there are so many examples already here, find a simple one and copy it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email with PHP from html form on submit with the same script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script)